# What kind of this electrical schematic?

Tags: schematics

I have to re-draw this schematic by Office Visio but don't know what kind of this schematic is, and how to find these components in Office Visio.

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of this electrical schematic?

It's a line diagram. It seems to show a mix of individual wires (such as the 24 V DC) and cables such as those going to be box on the bottom left.

> I have to re-draw this schematic by Office Visio ...

Not a great idea. If you only have one drawing it may be OK. If you have a lot of work get an electrical CAD package.

> ...and how to find these components in Office Visio.

It's unlikely that you'll find exactly what you want and you'll have to create the symbols you need and add connection 'X' connector attachment points to the appropriate places in the symbols. There are many good tutorials on the web.